# generating multidimensional dynamic javascript array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to generate `n` arrays with a for loop and push an extra element from another array of `n` using for loop to each of these arrays.

```
var userlist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'];

var selectlist = ['c', 'f', 'k'];

get_field_options = userlist.filter(function (el) {
    return selectlist.indexOf(el) < 0;
});

var selectlen = selectlist.length;
var op_arr = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < selectlen; i++) {
    op_arr[i] = new Array();
    op_arr[i] = get_field_options;
    op_arr[i].push(selectlist[i]);
    console.log(op_arr[i]);
}
```

here is my working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shahinul87/tLfc2d7q/).

but its adding items to same array each time. what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Copy and paste your code into your question, formatted as code (use the {} icon), and include what you expect the result to be vs what the result actually is (precisely, showing the actual data, not a description of the data).

Comment: [The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line  `op_arr[i] = get_field_options;` makes your arrays reference to the same object.

You need to [clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object) `get_field_options` to get a new array.
One simple way to clone is to use JSON.stringify like this.

```
op_arr[i] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(get_field_options));
```

Comment: only when in `get_field_options` not circular reference

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way, use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) functions

```
var op_arr = selectlist.map(function(el){
    return get_field_options.concat(el);
});
```